# Changing month digit in Date.UTC() leads to change of timezone

Tags: javascript

When I run this code, the first date is shown in GMT, and the second in BST. Why is this? The calls to `Date.UTC` are identical apart from one changed digit, the month digit. That, to me, shouldn't warrant a change in timezone. Please note that I'm in London right now, so somehow the second date seems to be returning local time. Why is the timezone different for the two different dates?

```
var date1 = new Date(Date.UTC(2005,0,5,4,55,55));
alert(date1); // Wed Jan 05 2005 04:55:55 GMT+0000 (GMT)
var date2 = new Date(Date.UTC(2005,5,5,4,55,55)); // <-- 0 has been replaced by 5
alert(date2); // Sen Jun 05 2005 05:55:55 GMT+0100 (BST)
```

Comment: Because Javascript dates are based on localtime,.. And 5th of May is British Summer Time,..

Comment: You are sure you tested these two lines in the same environnement? For me [**it works perfectly**](https://imgur.com/sSnclin) as you can see.

Comment: @chsdk So does your country have British Summer Time too?

Comment: @Keith No it's not **Date.UTC() uses universal time instead of the local time.**, you can see it in the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC).

Comment: @chsdk Date.UTC(), is just setting the Date using UTC, it's not responsible for displaying..

Comment: For display you need to use the reverse of you UTC, eg.  `date2.toUTCString()`

Comment: @Keith well pointed out, :)

Answer (score 1):

Using Date.UTC(), only effects setting the date using UTC.

As default Javascript dates display using localtime.

So if you wish to see the dates in UTC format,. 
You can't just use the default toString() implementation, as that will use localtime version.

But what you can do is use the UTC variants for display.  eg.  `toUTCString()` and also `toISOString()`.

```js
var date2 = new Date(Date.UTC(2005,5,5,4,55,55));

//if you say live in the UK, this date in localtime is
//British Summer Time,..
//eg. Sun Jun 05 2005 05:55:55 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time)
//if your running this script from another country
//your likely to see something different.
console.log(date2.toString());

//here we show the date in UTC, it will be same
//whatever country your running this from
//eg. Sun, 05 Jun 2005 04:55:55 GMT
console.log(date2.toUTCString());

//for an easier to parse date, 
//eg. 2005-06-05T04:55:55.000Z
console.log(date2.toISOString());
```